# ASP.NET - JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

To write JQuery in traditional asp.net with in VS what are the pre requisites has to be installed? any plug in kind of the thing has to be  installed?

Expecting yours help.

Thanks
Ka

Comment: You need to add jquery file OR use it from google or microsoft site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special is required - just include the Jquery scripts. These days the recommended way is to link to a CDN like Google or Amazon this gives you more info:

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

This may help if you're new to JQuery (interactive demos): http://visualjquery.com/

With ASP.Net the key thing to remember is that as the framework writes client-side IDs automatically, you'll mostly be accessing your controls by their type and css classname rather than by ID. You can use multiple css classnames to allow you to find/filter your HTML controls.

Good luck.

Comment: ASP.NET 4 includes different modes for generating ID's to help with the client-side ID munging problems.

Comment: Ah ok, noted. I'm still runnng 3.5 :-(

Comment: For script embedded in aspx pages, you can reference things in jQuery by ID easily enough using code like `$('#<%=MyControl.ClientID%>')` in any version of asp.net. Not a big deal.

Comment: @jamietre - I would be inclined to disagree.

For one thing, you shouldn't really be embedding script in webforms nowadays. C.f.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941272/jquery-best-way-of-wiring-gui-objects-to-events

For all but trivial applications it would very quickly become 'a big deal' in terms of maintenance and readability.

Comment: I was just speaking to the technical problem, not suggesting you write tons of code with that construct embedded throughout. While I don't disagree with you, should this mean you don't use jquery with asp.net <4? You can still have the majority of your code in includes and just include script in the webforms that calls functions (or add all the hooks in codebehind). There is no reason hardcoded dom element references need to be included in any substantive code, they should be parameters.

Comment: I dont disagree - the syntax you mention *will* work and using an older version of ASP.Net shouldn't prevent you from using JQuery to tart-up your site/application. if you read up the thread you'll see that I for one haven't yet used JQuery with ASP.Net v.4 :-)

But given JQuery's extensive support for CSS&tag selectors I would advise the OP, assuming he's using a pre-version 4 .Net, to go down that road. Also I'd suggest he separate his .js files from his markup, rather than getting bogged down with dreadful, messy markup interspersed with that old skool, ASP Classic-ish hackery ;-)

Comment: Agreed. I personally have a conceptual problem with using css selectors to identify the target of an operation just because it's not how I think of the purpose of css. And every time I've done it I end up with conflicts. But that's my own issue in rewiring years of server-side thinking...

Comment: Oh I hear you re: CSS - its taken me 2years of this 5hit to overcome my issues (I am an older coder) with using it to do something other than trivial prettification. Gotta move with the times though.  
  
Will definitely be taking a look at .Net v.4 - had avoided thus far. More manual rewiring of my brain looks to be on the cards now :-(

Comment: Ha ha... same boat. About 30 years ago I was writing machine code (in hex) on a vic 20, then when I went to college where c++ & oo programming blew my mind. Lately I have had to come to grips with the fact that UI development isn't just for graphic designers any more. It's tough being an old dog.

Comment: "Woof woof!" (Olddogese for 'Couldn't agree more') ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just include the jquery.js file in your page.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what's already been noted, here are a couple hints and gotchas to watch out for.

1) Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 support intellisense support for jQuery using vsdoc files. For 2008 you need SP1 or a patch. Either way, if you include a vsdoc file for a script in the same folder as your include, you will have design support, e.g. if you are using `jquery-1.4.2.js` then also include `jquery-1.4.2-vsdoc.js` in the same folder. The vsdoc files often lag behind the current version of jquery, but you can just rename the previous version which will mostly work too.

2) An asp.net 3.5 or lower you'll need to use ClientID to reference DOM id tags. Better alternatives are available in 4.0 (see previous answer). In a markup file, just use `<%=MyControl.ClientID %>`. Sometimes you may find it's convenient to set up some references in advance:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $modalPanel = $('#<%=modalPanel.ClientID %>');
  var $myLink = $('#<%=somethingElse.ClientID %>');
  ...
  // now you can write clean looking jquery code
  $myLink.click(function(e) {
    ..
  }
}
</script>
```

3) Mixing jQuery and UpdatePanels together is possible but understand that there can be conflicts. e.g. using jQuery to add events to asp.net-generated objects (as above with myLink) does not always work, because asp.net also adds client event code. Though conventional jQuery wisdom is it's best practice to add events with jQuery, with asp.net a lot of times you're better off adding them in codebehind so that they play correctly with the stuff asp.net adds itself. So instead of the above snippet to add a click handler, in codebehind you would do:

```
somethingElse.Attributes.Add("click","myLinkClickFunction()");
```

and in script:

```
function myLinkClickFunction()
{
  $modalPanel.dialog();
}
```

4) In asp.net there's always just one form with id "aspnetForm" that everything which talks to the server should live inside. Sometimes jquery things (like modal dialogs) need to know about this.

5) When you get into using ajax, jquery can talk to asp.net just fine, but the way most people do it with jQuery doesn't quite work for asp.net. There's probably a lot to say about the nuances, but generally speaking, get the jquery-json plugin and build ajax queries like this:

```
var ajaxData = { parm1: 'value1',
    parm: 'value2'
};
// you will probably use other options too (success, error, asycn) 
$.ajax({
            url: "/my/webservice.asmx/MyMethodName",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: $.toJSON(ajaxData),
        });
```

The key here is you need to serialize the jQuery object to a string. This seems to not be the case for php (and  in most examples) so it can be confusing until you figure it out.

Have fun!

Comment: Good post. Still don't approve of putting substantial scripts in markup files though.

Comment: I agree, but there is a balance between the best architecture and convenience in any situation. A lot more could be said about that (and I'm probably not the best person to say it) but hopefully this will help some people get over the first hump with jquery & asp.net.